# What determines when my Apple Watch uses a haptic tap for a notification?

Tags: notifications, apple-watch

Some notifications on my Apple Watch (e.g. [Viber](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/viber/id382617920?mt=8)) use a haptic tap when they appear on my Apple Watch. Others (e.g. [Facebook](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/facebook/id284882215?mt=8)) do not. What determines whether a haptic tap is used or not? Is this something I can change?

Comment: If it happens consistently on a per-app basis for multiple users, it could be a decision made by the app's developers.

Answer (score 1):

From [this Apple Discussion:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7023702)

> There are variations. The 3rd party app developers have some control over what you get, but they won't have been able to check it before launch - they'll have been using a simulator.

This can currently not be changed by the user.

To turn haptic feedback of:

1. Open the Settings app.
2. Scroll down and tap Sounds & Haptics.
3. Turn Haptic Alerts on or off.

Answer (score 0):

> **What determines whether a haptic tap is used or not? Is this something I can change?**

There are two types of haptic feedback:

- System provided
- Application provided

This means that in addition to the ones provided iOS, app developers can implement haptic feedback as they see fit.

Looking at [Apple Developer's Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/user-interaction/feedback/), it states:

> Some system-provided interface elements, such as pickers, switches,
>   and sliders, automatically provide haptic feedback as users interact
>   with them. Your app can also ask the system to generate different
>   types of haptic feedback. iOS manages the strength and behavior of
>   this feedback.

Can you (the end user) enable this manually?  Not unless the haptic feedback was implemented by the developer and gives you the option to selectively disable.  From a system-wide perspective, you can only enable or disable all of them.

> Not all devices support the full range of haptic feedback, and people can disable the feature entirely in Settings if they choose.